# cannot deploy web app from github to azure

Tags: azure, github

I am using GitHub for Azure. Suddenly, Azure stopped deploying from GitHub. It was working fine before. Below is the error i am getting now.

> Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd" Handling .NET Web
>   Application deployment. MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version
>   '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'. Restoring NuGet
>   package DotNetZip.1.10.1. Restoring NuGet package
>   Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0. Restoring NuGet package
>   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0. Restoring
>   NuGet package FontAwesome.4.7.0. Adding package 'FontAwesome.4.7.0' to
>   folder 'D:\home\site\repository\packages' Adding package
>   'Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0' to folder
>   'D:\home\site\repository\packages' Adding package 'DotNetZip.1.10.1'
>   to folder 'D:\home\site\repository\packages' Adding package
>   'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0' to folder
>   'D:\home\site\repository\packages' Added package 'DotNetZip.1.10.1' to
>   folder 'D:\home\site\repository\packages' Restoring NuGet package
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.15.0.4795.1000. Adding package
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.15.0.4795.1000' to folder
>   'D:\home\site\repository\packages' Added package
>   'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0' to folder
>   'D:\home\site\repository\packages' Restoring NuGet package
>   SharpZipLib.0.86.0. Adding package 'SharpZipLib.0.86.0' to folder
>   'D:\home\site\repository\packages' Added package
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.15.0.4795.1000' to folder
>   'D:\home\site\repository\packages' Added package 'FontAwesome.4.7.0'
>   to folder 'D:\home\site\repository\packages' Added package
>   'SharpZipLib.0.86.0' to folder 'D:\home\site\repository\packages'
>   Added package 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0' to folder
>   'D:\home\site\repository\packages'
>
> NuGet Config files used:
>       C:\DWASFiles\Sites#1RBCAPP\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.Config
>
> Feeds used:
>       D:\home.nuget
>       https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
>
> Installed:
>       6 package(s) to packages.config projects D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2398,5):
>   warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library
>   "c3d19104-7a67-4eb0-b459-d5b2e734d430" version 1.0. Library not
>   registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D
>   (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
>   [D:\home\site\repository\PortalApp\PortalApp.csproj]   PortalApp ->
>   D:\home\site\repository\PortalApp\bin\PortalApp.dll   Transformed
>   Web.config using D:\home\site\repository\PortalApp\Web.Release.config
>   into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.   Copying
>   all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
>   D:\local\Temp\8d45a9ead3c2d9c. D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3010,5):
>   error : Copying file Files\def.html to
>   D:\local\Temp\8d45a9ead3c2d9c\Files\def.html failed. Could not find
>   file 'Files\def.html'.
>   [D:\home\site\repository\PortalApp\PortalApp.csproj] Failed
>   exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
>   "D:\home\site\repository\PortalApp\PortalApp.csproj" /nologo
>   /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder
>   /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d45a9ead3c2d9c";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false
>   /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository.\" An error has occurred
>   during web site deployment. \r\nD:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\59.60207.2684\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd
>   "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your build is failing because `Files\def.html` which is referenced in your project `PortalApp.csproj` is missing and the build is giving up. You might want to remove the file from your project or reinstate the file to make msbuild, and the deployment happy again.